# gdb says "cannot open shared object file"

Tags: c++, linux, emacs, gdb

I have one binary and one shared library.
The shared library is compiled with:

```
all:
g++ -g -shared -fpic $(SOURCES) -o libmisc.so
```

the binary is compiled with:

```
LIBS=-L../../misc/src

LDFLAGS=-lmisc

all:
g++ -g -o mainx $(INCLUDE) $(SOURCE) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

I set in `~/.bashrc`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/sda5/Programming/misc/src/
```

to the `libmisc.so` output path.

Debugging from console works fine:

```
gdb mainx
```

However from Emacs22, launching gdb fails with the following message:

> Starting program: /mnt/sda5/Programming/main/src/mainx
>   /mnt/sda5/Programming/main/src/mainx: error while loading shared libraries: libmisc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This looks very tricky for the moment, and I couldn't solve it. I am not sure if this a emacs's problem, or I should pass a parameter in gdb's command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Emacs probably does not read your .bashrc before it invokes gdb. Try to put 'set solib-search-path' and 'set solib-absolute-path in your .gdbinit file instead

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
It worked very well. 
I searched previously the gdb manual with key words to find a quick answer but I failed.  You saved my day :)
I will read of course the gdb manual in depth these days.
vmihai.

Answer (score 5):

Emacs doesn't invoke gdb via bash, but rather invokes it directly, and so .bashrc changes do not take effect and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set.

If you quit emacs, open a new shell (so `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set), start emacs in it, and then do `M-X gdb`, then it would work.

Setting `solib-search-path` in GDB is a hack.

A much better fix is to build the executable in such a way that it doesn't need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to begin with:

```
LDFLAGS=-lmisc -Wl,-rpath=/mnt/sda5/Programming/misc/src
```

Comment: Not available on all platforms, and when it is, -rpath has it's problems too:

[rpath(linking)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath_(linking))

It's always a tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
That sounds reasonable also.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to create a `.gdbinit` file in your `$HOME` and set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH there:

```
# file .gdbinit
set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/sda5/Programming/misc/src/
```

This is convenient if you need to debug with that LD_LIBRARY_PATH frequently (and don't want to remember running emacs from your shell every time).