# why i cannot debug the free program which is build from procps package in emacs gdb-mode?

Tags: debugging, emacs, gdb, shared-libraries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gdb says “cannot open shared object file”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932384/gdb-says-cannot-open-shared-object-file)

This free program is part of the command which [procps package]: http://procps.sourceforge.net/procps-3.2.8.tar.gz provides

I have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/hugemeow/workspace/linuxc/packages/procps-3.2.8/proc`, so I can debug this free command in eshell,

```
Mx shell
gdb free
br main
r
// the debug works well here
```

but when i try to debug in emacs's gdb-mode, i fails to debug this program.

when i hit

```
r
Enter
```

the error just appears, it shows `"error while loading shared libraries: libproc-3.2.8.so"`, 
[image: Failed to debug free command in emacs's gdb-mode]

but i have setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and it works well in eshell, so what's the reason I failed to debug free command? and what i should do in order to debug free command in emacs's gdb-mode?

Comment: Please *do not* post pictures (and unreadable pictures at that) when a simple text cut/paste would convey just as much info (I've already asked you once).

Comment: @EmployedRussian you can read that pic, if open the pic in new window:) since this pic is embeded in the paged now, for layout reasons, you have to open it in new window if you want to see a one which is more larger:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error while loading shared libraries: libproc-3.2.8.so

The reason GDB didn't stop on `main` is because `main` never executed. The `free` program requires `libproc-3.2.8.so` to be loaded, and the dynamic linker (which is responsible for loading it) couldn't find it. So the dynamic loader exited your program before even the first instruction of your program has executed.

You *must* set the environment such that dynamic loader *can* find required library. The easiest way is to *properly* install `libproc-3.2.8.so` on the system. A slightly harder way is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` such that `libproc-3.2.8.so` is found via it. For example:

```
(gdb) set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH /path/to/libproc/lib
(gdb) run
```

> I have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Chances are you did above *after* starting `emacs`, or you started `emacs` via menu or ar an application launcher, and *not* by invoking from the shell in which `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` was set. Environment variables don't get inherited by processes that are started before the environment variable is set, or started from a different shell.